# XPath position where text (or attribute) is equal to value

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, position

XML:

```
<row type="header">
 <column>href</column>
 <column>other</column>
</row>
<row type="data">
 <column>a</column>
 <column>b</column>
</row>
```

XSLT:(I'm making sure I'm in row[@type='data']/column in the template below)

```
<xsl:template match="column" mode="panelTabsBody">
 <td>
  <a>
   <xsl:attribute name="href">
    <xsl:value-of select="../../row[@type='header']/column[text()='href'][position()]" />
   </xsl:attribute>
  </a>
 </td>
</xsl:template>
```

How can I get the column position where the text() is equal to href? If it's easier, I can give the column with the value 'href' an attribute. Example: `<column type='link'>href</column>`

**Edit:**
I tried the following, but this didnt work
XSLT:

```
<xsl:template match="column" mode="panelTabsBody">
 <xsl:variable name="testt" select="count(../../row[@type='header']/column[text()='href']/preceding-sibling::column) + 1" />
 <td>
  <a>
   <xsl:attribute name="href">
    <xsl:value-of select="../../row[@type='header']/column[position() = testt]" />
   </xsl:attribute>
  </a>
 </td>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple answer is that `testt` is a variable, so you need to use a `$` prefix to reference it

```
<xsl:value-of select="../../row[@type='header']/column[position() = $testt]" />
```

Of course, this is selecting the column for the 'header' row, which you already know contains "href". Perhaps you just need to do this?

```
<xsl:value-of select="../column[position() = $testt]" />
```