# How can I get the Index position using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xquery, xsd-validation

```
<root>    
<row type="header">
 <column>href</column>
 <column>other</column>
</row>
<row type="data">
 <column>a</column>
 <column>b</column>
</row>
</root>
```

XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="row">
        <xsl:if test="">
            <xsl:value-of select="column"/>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I want to know the position of column which contains "a" in it based on condition row type="data" only

Comment: Post your XSLT as well as required output in XML format.

Comment: Why do you (think that you) need this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [XPath position where text (or attribute) is equal to value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27354417/xpath-position-where-text-or-attribute-is-equal-to-value)

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<!-- Edited by XMLSpy® -->
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
<xsl:for-each select="row">
 <xsl:if test="">
  <xsl:value-of select="column"/>
</xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>        in this code  in if condition i want to filter based on row type="data"

Comment: Please don't post code in comments - edit your question instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:template match="root">
    <xsl:for-each select="row[@type='data']/column">
        <xsl:if test="contains(., 'a')">
            <xsl:value-of select="position()"/>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: @AnshuKumar, you are welcome, in future posts, place your input xml, tried XSLT, and required out put.